# Event handler is executed before the event is fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom dropdown that is triggered by a button. If it is expanded, then isExpanded===true. To close it, I use useEffect, which adds a click handler to the entire document only if isExpanded is true.
The problem: the click handler is triggered as soon as I click on the button even before it is assigned, and therefore the dropdown content immediately disappears (does not appear on the page).
It feels like document.addEventListener is assigned before useEffect fires.

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isExpanded) {
    return;
  }

  const handleDocumentClick = () => {
    setIsExpanded(false);
  };

  document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);
  };
}, [isExpanded]);

<button
  type="button"
  onClick={setIsExpanded(current => !current)}
  >
  Sort by:
</button>

<div
  style={{ display: isExpanded ? 'block' : 'none' }}
>
  Some content
</div>
```

I've tried moving the logic from useEffect directly to the button handler, but the document.addEventListener still fires before it's assigned.

Comment: Try e.preventDefault or e.stopImmediatePropogation on the click event from the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the event propagation in the button click handler.

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        setIsExpanded(current => !current);
    }}>
    Sort by:
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify your button's click handler to accept the event parameter and call event.stopPropagation() to prevent the event from propagating further:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setIsExpanded((current) => !current);
  }}
>
  Sort by:
</button>
```

By stopping the event propagation, the document-level click event won't be triggered immediately after clicking the button, allowing the dropdown content to appear correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Victoria Hill!

All six of your answers here appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.